# Trailing slash in try_files causing 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, regex, nginx

A little background first. I have some extensionless files in my nginx config that get directed to a php file, so for example:

/galleries/1/17/22 calls /galleries.php?mypath=$mypath&$args

The galleries location try_files also checks to see if a static version exists. This has been working fine for years on my previous CentOS server but I'm migrating to a Ubuntu server and suddenly I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway error if anyone calls /galleries/. Calling /galleries without the trailing slash works without issue.

First, here's the location:

```
location ~ ^/galleries(?P<mypath>/.*$|$) {
error_log  /var/log/nginx/galerrors.log debug;
try_files /pixcache$request_uri/index.html /galleries.php?mypath=$mypath&$args;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

If someone calls, say, /galleries/51/646/31 the debug logs shows:

```
trying to use file: "/pixcache/galleries/51/646/31/index.html" 
"/usr/share/nginx/html/pixcache/galleries/51/646/31/index.html"
```

If it doesn't find a static version debug shows:

```
trying to use file: "/galleries.php?mypath=/51/646/31&" 
"/usr/share/nginx/html/galleries.php?mypath=/51/646/31&"
```

All works fine. However, if someone tries to call the main page, with /galleries/, we get this:

```
trying to use file: "/pixcache/galleries//index.html" 
"/usr/share/nginx/html/pixcache/galleries//index.html"
trying to use file: "/galleries.php?mypath=/&" 
"/usr/share/nginx/html/galleries.php?mypath=/&"
```

Note the double slashes '//' in the static file check and the dynamic gall is tossing the bad gateway. The old server ran fine for years with this location so I'm really scrathing my head here. I've been staring at it for hours now. I suck at regex, but could it be something to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

For double slashes problem you can activate the directive

```
merge_slashes
```

For more info how to do it [visit here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes)

Comment: It didn't work. Added merge_slashes on to the config. Restarted nginx and the try files still has the trailing slash: `trying to use file: "/pixcache/galleries//index.html" "/usr/share/nginx/html/pixcache/galleries//index.html"`